# How does this bot steal money from v2 liquidity after each trade?

Tags: blockchain, solidity

I caught this bot withdrawing money from v2 liquidity pool after each trade. Blacklisting them in the contract doesn't work. Does anyone have any idea how they are doing it? What exploit are they using?

The withdrawals are coming from these two addresses:

0xc1bc33517b0a28dca900a739b5274c4ab1fc3b0b

0xdf0ad9c9eeb5ebcbb4177695072b24d7f2a1a12c

This is the contract they are using:

0xFB301dF3B715aA3D337AE1FDF6B71D4116842Da0

Comment: how do you know they are stealing from the liquidity pool ?

Comment: There's is no swap, they are just straight up withdrawing from the pool without any trade

Comment: Another tell is that I cannot blacklist this address nor the contract in my ERC contract

Comment: It would be super helpful to have a transaction hash for one of the times they are doing something that the contract should disallow. Those two accounts have around 100,000 transactions between them at the moment. Hard to know which one is the issue.

Also, is your contract FatherDoge? If so the source code is not verified, so it will be difficult be able to say anything about the code.